# Set error on the ListView Item Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview i want to check whether it's value has been changed or not .I have a array that i am using to create a ListView.

```
String [] list  = {"A1","A2","A3"};
String []listData;
```

This is how i am getting the changed data of the listview item

```
int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
    listData = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        listData[i] = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
    }
```

This is how i am creating the ListView

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now OnClick of a button i want to compare both the array (**list and listdata**) if the value has not been changed of any item then seterror on that item ,i.e value has not been changed .Please suggest me how could i do this

Comment: Please explain your question a little more. its not clear. do you want to check whether the previously held values in your 'list' have changed ?

Comment: Are you using custom adapter?

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan yup u r right i have to check whether the previous values has been chnaged or not.if any of the value in the listview is not changed then seterror on that

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Remove this code :

```
int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
listData = new String[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    listData[i] = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
}
```

Add this code on button click:

```
for(int i=0;i<listView.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
   if(list[i]==listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString()){
    View v=listView.getChaildAt(i);
    TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setError("Please change the data");
  }
}
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @vijay what will u do if list[0] equals to list[2]

Comment: this is not the proper answer

Comment: vishal how could i update the value of a item in the listview .I have the postion that i have to update .please suggest

Comment: i have done this View v=listView.getChildAt(position);
        TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setText(firstNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().toString()+" "+lastNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().toString());

Comment: Ya exactly. and you need to call listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Sorry in my answer I forgot to typecast the view to textView

Comment: @VishalVijay it is cheking the value at only one position that is i.i have to compare i listData

Comment: What you mean by checking only one position. This code will check each item in the `list` array with current value of each list item of your list view respectively .